# Reading incoming request string in python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

Is there any way that I can read an incoming message from a client using 'socket' in python? 
What I am looking for is a way to do without using SocketServer. It doesn't work in my case. 
For example, I have the following piece of code to 'accept' the incoming connection? but how can I get the incoming string from this?

```
import socket

def serve(self):
    listener=socket.socket()
    listener.bind(('',6000))
    listener.listen(5)

    while True:
        sockadd, c =listener.accept()

        # can I write the accepted request string??? 
        # Is there a way to do it?
```

I have tried `listener.recv(1024)` it gives an exception.

help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sockadd` is a socket representing the connection with the client here, so use it to send and receive message with the client.

`data = sockadd.recv(1024)`

Check the [socket documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), there are several samples.